# Doxygen: place repeating parts of documentation (like badges) in single place

Tags: doxygen

I use doxygen to document [real-time kernel written in C](http://goo.gl/f2YReU), and for each function I should specify at least the following:

- whether the function may be called from task
- whether the function may be called from ISR
- whether the function could lead to context switch

I'd like to implement these properties of functions as a kind of badge: probably just an image, probably an image with text, or something like that.

So, I'd like to put actual doxygen markup of all possible badges (currently, just three ones) in one place, and then just "include" them in the documentation of each function. Unfortunately I can't find anything about this in doxygen docs. I see there are methods to include source file as an example: `\include`, or even par or it: `\snippet`, but how to include documentation snippet?

I can't believe this isn't possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I failed to find some straightforward way, so I ended up with hacky makefile environment variables approach:

Makefile:

```
define \n


endef

TN_CALL_FROM_TASK     = \image html attr_call_task.png ${\n}\
                        \latexonly \
                        \includegraphics{../../images/attr_call_task.png} \
                        \endlatexonly \

TN_CALL_FROM_ISR      = \image html attr_call_int.png ${\n} \
                        \latexonly \
                        \includegraphics{../../images/attr_call_int.png} \
                        \endlatexonly \

export TN_CALL_FROM_TASK
export TN_CALL_FROM_ISR

all: 
    doxygen tn_doxyfile
```

And then, in the code:

```
/**
 * Some docs for my function
 * 
 * $(TN_CALL_FROM_TASK)
 */
void my_func(void) { ... }
```

It's not particularly elegant, but works.

Note one drawback of this approach: in doxygen 1.8.8 (latest at the moment), markdown syntax doesn't work when expanded from environment variables.